# neo4j shortestPath query relationship where

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

Below is query to return shortest path.

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((a:Person{pid:"aaa"})-[:IS_RELATED_TO*1..3]->(b:Person{fid:"bb"})) RETURN p
```

is returning correct result:

[image]

But my requirement is to return shortestpath with relationship having property named "status" = 'approved'.

So I tried with following query.

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((a:Person{pid:"aaa"})-[:IS_RELATED_TO*1..3]->(b:Person{fid:"bb"})) 
WHERE ALL(x IN relationships(p) WHERE x.status='approved') 
RETURN p
```

which is not returning expected result.

Comment: The query looks fine, so my guess is your the problem may be in your data. Can you double check that there is such a path where every :IS_RELATED_TO relationship going that direction has status='approved'? If you can supply some sample data or cypher creation queries so we can recreate this it may help.

Comment: Thank you so much @InverseFalcon. You are correct. There is no data satisfying that condition. So I cross checked with different nodes where all relationships are having status = 'approved', which is returning expected result and working fine.